# GRUB screen freezes after installing Ubuntu dual boot with Windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, boot-repair

I recently bought a HP Spectre x360 laptop with Windows 10 on it. I manually created a partition for it using Windows. I then installed Ubuntu 18.04.02 by choosing the 'Install Ubuntu alongside Windows' option. I checked that Windows and Ubuntu both still work well.

My problem is that when I turn the computer on, it shows the GRUB menu and freezes. No key commands help. Now I can only boot either OS by using F9 - Change boot order.

Things I have tried:
Ensuring that Legacy Boot is off, Secure boot off, and fast boot off
Reinstalling GRUB
Running boot-repair

Boot-repair generated the info shown in this link: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/VG5gZj83D4/

I am aware that this question is similar to this one: [Grub freezes when naturally booting, but works when selected from EFI menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966991/grub-freezes-when-naturally-booting-but-works-when-selected-from-efi-menu), but that person seems not to have found a solution.

I think it could have something to do with the way I partitioned the space for Ubuntu but I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: It looks like Windows may be hibernated or fast start up is on. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions Directly Boot Windows from UEFI boot menu to turn off fast start up. HP Pavillion X360 13-a220nw
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2359510 HP needs UEFI update & may need you to set boot order in UEFI, not with efibootmgr or grub. https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers  You may need video mode in grub to match system video using GRUB_GFXMODE= to your correct  X by Y size. See Boot-Repair advanced options.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions @oldfred. I am sure that hibernate and fast boot are disabled. I don't think it's a UEFI issue because I was able to install Ubuntu and it boots via the Boot Options Manager without any noticeable error. The only issue is the GRUB screen itself. I also tried changing GRUB_GFXMODE, and the problem is still there.

Answer (score 1):

So, I seem to have fixed my own problem. I was under the impression that Legacy boot should be off, but after enabling it, the issue seems to have disappeared. I haven't noticed any other adverse effects since.

Comment: I have the exact same problem and the exact same laptop as you, can you please tell me how I can enable Legacy boot?