# Grub menu freezes after reboot but works fine on first launch

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.04, grub2, uefi

I have an issue with GRUB that started appearing just some time ago.

I have a dual-boot Ubuntu 18.04 and Win10 on a Dell Precision 5530 laptop. If I reboot from Ubuntu, then grub menu will freeze with countdown stuck at 10s and grub not responding to input.
It works just fine in other situations, i.e. reboot from Windows, or booting Ubuntu on first launch after shutdown. So something happens when I restart from Ubuntu.

I'm not that good with boot and grub hence have no idea where to dig and couldn't find anything helpful in search as well.

I've found [Grub freezes when naturally booting, but works when selected from EFI menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966991/grub-freezes-when-naturally-booting-but-works-when-selected-from-efi-menu) but it doesn't seem applicable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out this was caused by a USB dongle.